# How to print £ € with esc_pos_utils_plus flutter

Tags: flutter, thermal-printer

I'm trying to print £ and € sign with [esc_pos_utils_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_utils_plus) package for [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004056240628.html) printer but it prints **Û** .

When I use following profile:

```
final profile = await CapabilityProfile.load('XP-N160I');
final generator = Generator(PaperSize.mm80, profile);
bytes += generator.setGlobalCodeTable('CP1252');
```

The code:

```
   List<int> bytes = [];
      final profile = await CapabilityProfile.load('XP-N160I');
      final generator = Generator(PaperSize.mm80, profile);
      bytes += generator.setGlobalCodeTable('CP1252'); //I have also tested CP437
      bytes +=  generator.text("Amount £50");
      bytes += generator.cut();
      await _print(data: bytes);
```

Here, the output is `Amount 50` But if I remove profile and GlobalCodeTable, the output is `Amount Û50` 
 How to fix this?

Comment: Why not try it with some other language or tool? For example, like this tool provided by EPSON? [Send Data Tool](https://www.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5027&scat=47&pcat=52) If it still doesn't work, then it's probably a problem with the printer or its settings, and if you can do it with another tool, it's probably a problem with your program or the library you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, i am able to print in XP-N160I

May be u need to set the correct code page also in printer

generator.rawBytes([0x80]);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).